# Aggregate Same Dataframe by Month and by Quarter

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with a date column in the format DD/MM/YYYY. I want to aggregate my data by month and by quarter. I want to create a column called 'Period' with rows that will say either 'Monthly' or 'Quarterly' - where the 'Monthly' rows will have an aggregate data value associated with them and the 'Quarterly' rows will be aggregated based on quarter.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas library in Python to achieve this. Here is an example on  how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Date': ['01/01/2023', '15/01/2023', '01/02/2023', '15/02/2023', '01/03/2023'],
        'Value': [100, 150, 200, 120, 180]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Quarter'] = df['Date'].dt.quarter
df['Period'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Monthly' if row['Month'] == 1 else 'Quarterly', axis=1)

result = df.groupby(['Period', 'Date'])['Value'].sum().reset_index()

print(result)
```

Comment: Why are you setting if row['Month'] == 1 else 'Quarterly - what does this do? Also, I want to specifically aggregate by fiscal quarters so the first quarter would be April - June, etc.